# Threading sqlite connections in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sqlite, parallel-processing

I've been trying to get my ruby script threaded since yesterday. I've since opted for SQLite to save data, with the parallel gem to manage concurrency.

I've built a quick script for testing, but I'm having trouble getting the threading working; the database is locked. I've added db.close to the end, which doesn't help, and I've tried adding sleep until db.closed?, but that just sleeps indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

The error is "database is locked (SQLite3::BusyException)".

Here's my code:

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'pry'
require 'parallel'
STDOUT.sync = true
db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

rows = db.execute <<-SQL
create table test_table (
    original string,
    conversion string
);
SQL

def test(num)
    db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"
    puts "the num: #{num}"
    sleep 4
    { num => num + 10}.each do |pair|
        db.execute "insert into test_table values (?, ?)", pair
    end
    db.close
end

Parallel.each( -> { arr.pop || Parallel::Stop}, in_processes: 3) { |number| test(number) }
```

Comment: SQLLite does not support conccurent write. You should either limit them or use an onther SQL engine

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is threadsafe by default (using its "serialized" mode) and the ruby wrapper apparently supports this to whatever extent it needs to. However, it's not safe across *processes*, which makes a certain sense since the adapter or engine probably has to negotiate some state in the process to prevent locks.

To fix your example change `in_processes` to `in_threads`